# People API not returning correct Status code

Tags: google-people-api

The people API batchCreate API endpoint must give the error code for each of the person created, But I am seeing the status object as {}

The documentation states httpStatusCode should not be used since its depreciated
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/PersonResponse

The status must contain as described here
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/Status

My response is always empty status!

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "contactPerson": {
        "emailAddresses": [
          {
            "type": "work",
            "value": "airisatou@company.com"
          }
        ],
        "names": [
          {
            "unstructuredName": "Airi Satou"
          }
        ],
        "memberships": [
          {
            "contactGroupMembership": {
              "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/1ccba93f8f596c2b"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "contactPerson": {
        "emailAddresses": [
          {
            "type": "work",
            "value": "angelicaramos@company.com"
          }
        ],
        "names": [
          {
            "unstructuredName": "Angelica Ramos"
          }
        ],
        "memberships": [
          {
            "contactGroupMembership": {
              "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/42974c738f7cf661"
            }
          },
          {
            "contactGroupMembership": {
              "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/1ccba93f8f596c2b"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "contactPerson": {
        "emailAddresses": [
          {
            "type": "work",
            "value": "ashtoncox@company.com"
          }
        ],
        "names": [
          {
            "unstructuredName": "Ashton Cox"
          }
        ],
        "memberships": [
          {
            "contactGroupMembership": {
              "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/6781cd468fa0dff4"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "contactPerson": {
        "emailAddresses": [
          {
            "type": "work",
            "value": "bradleygreer@company.com"
          }
        ],
        "names": [
          {
            "unstructuredName": "Bradley Greer"
          }
        ],
        "memberships": [
          {
            "contactGroupMembership": {
              "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/42974c738f7cf662"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "readMask": "metadata,memberships"
}
```

Where I am doing wrong?

The response only contains depreciated httpStatusCode without status

```
{
    "createdPeople": [{
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "person": {
                "resourceName": "people/c1544006860171223365",
                "etag": "%EgMBLjcaBAECBQciDElNQ0p0QTBNVXhzPQ==",
                "metadata": {
                    "sources": [{
                        "type": "CONTACT",
                        "id": "156d6a0f0f45a145",
                        "etag": "#IMCJtA0MUxs=",
                        "updateTime": "2021-09-04T10:03:36.257634Z"
                    }],
                    "objectType": "PERSON"
                },
                "memberships": [{
                    "metadata": {
                        "source": {
                            "type": "CONTACT",
                            "id": "156d6a0f0f45a145"
                        }
                    },
                    "contactGroupMembership": {
                        "contactGroupId": "myContacts",
                        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/myContacts"
                    }
                }]
            },
            "requestedResourceName": "people/c1544006860171223365",
            "status": {}
        },
        {
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "person": {
                "resourceName": "people/c2087956670693311718",
                "etag": "%EgMBLjcaBAECBQciDElNQ0p0QTBNVXhzPQ==",
                "metadata": {
                    "sources": [{
                        "type": "CONTACT",
                        "id": "1cf9e9878f1504e6",
                        "etag": "#IMCJtA0MUxs=",
                        "updateTime": "2021-09-04T10:03:36.257634Z"
                    }],
                    "objectType": "PERSON"
                },
                "memberships": [{
                    "metadata": {
                        "source": {
                            "type": "CONTACT",
                            "id": "1cf9e9878f1504e6"
                        }
                    },
                    "contactGroupMembership": {
                        "contactGroupId": "myContacts",
                        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/myContacts"
                    }
                }]
            },
            "requestedResourceName": "people/c2087956670693311718",
            "status": {}
        },
        {
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "person": {
                "resourceName": "people/c1667117179921365184",
                "etag": "%EgMBLjcaBAECBQciDElNQ0p0QTBNVXhzPQ==",
                "metadata": {
                    "sources": [{
                        "type": "CONTACT",
                        "id": "1722ca3e0c29f8c0",
                        "etag": "#IMCJtA0MUxs=",
                        "updateTime": "2021-09-04T10:03:36.257634Z"
                    }],
                    "objectType": "PERSON"
                },
                "memberships": [{
                    "metadata": {
                        "source": {
                            "type": "CONTACT",
                            "id": "1722ca3e0c29f8c0"
                        }
                    },
                    "contactGroupMembership": {
                        "contactGroupId": "myContacts",
                        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/myContacts"
                    }
                }]
            },
            "requestedResourceName": "people/c1667117179921365184",
            "status": {}
        },
        {
            "httpStatusCode": 200,
            "person": {
                "resourceName": "people/c1712185358445368788",
                "etag": "%EgMBLjcaBAECBQciDElNQ0p0QTBNVXhzPQ==",
                "metadata": {
                    "sources": [{
                        "type": "CONTACT",
                        "id": "17c2e7830fc2d5d4",
                        "etag": "#IMCJtA0MUxs=",
                        "updateTime": "2021-09-04T10:03:36.257634Z"
                    }],
                    "objectType": "PERSON"
                },
                "memberships": [{
                    "metadata": {
                        "source": {
                            "type": "CONTACT",
                            "id": "17c2e7830fc2d5d4"
                        }
                    },
                    "contactGroupMembership": {
                        "contactGroupId": "myContacts",
                        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/myContacts"
                    }
                }]
            },
            "requestedResourceName": "people/c1712185358445368788",
            "status": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `status` is only populated if the request fails. Have you tried checking the `status` when the request fails?

Comment: Correct. Thats sounds an incorrect documentation.

Comment: Well, the documentation about [Status](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/Status) clearly states it is for errors: `The Status type defines a logical error model that is suitable for different programming environments, including REST APIs and RPC APIs. It is used by gRPC. Each Status message contains three pieces of data: error code, error message, and error details.`